# "Update Links when Loading" - what exactly it updates?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-writer

> Tools > Options > LibreOffice Writer > General > Update Links when Loading

What is this setting is actually used for? Which links does it update?

(For example, when I moved my document with linked images to another directory, there was no warning, despite the setting was set on "On request".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First, let's test it with Calc.**

Assuming you are on Windows, create the directory `test` in the root of the drive C, and put there two Calc spreadsheets: `a.ods` and `b.ods`.

1. In the A1 cell of `a.ods` type `hello`.
2. In the A1 cell of `b.ods` type `='file:///C:/test/a.ods'#$Sheet1.A1`, so now you have `hello` in both files.

Now adjust the LibreOffice security settings:

1. Tools > Options > LibreOffice > Security
2. Macro Security > Trusted Sources
3. Add `C:\test` to the trusted file locations

Now speficy whether Calc should update links when you open a file:

1. Tools > Options > LibreOffice Calc > General
2. Set "Update links when opening" to "Always", "On request", or "Never".

Close both files, open `a.ods`, change the value from `hello` to `hello world`, then open `b.ods`.

- If you have selected "Always", the value in the A1 cell of the `b.ods` will be `hello world`
- If you have selected "On request", the value will be `hello`, but you also have a yellow ribbon to update it to `hello world`

  [image]
- If you have selected "Never", there will be just `hello`.

**Second, let's test it with Writer.**

Create two new files in the same `C:\test` directory:

- `plain-text.txt` with any text inside
- `writer-document.odt`

Open the Writer document and insert plain text file as a linked section:

1. Insert > Section
2. Enable the "Link" check box
3. Select the "Browse" button and then select your `plain-text.txt`

So you have inserted your `plain-text.txt` as a linked section.

Close the document, edit the `plain-text.txt`, open the document again, and see what is going on.

- If you have selected "Always", the text will be updated
- If you have selected "On request", you will have a confirmation window first.

  [image]
- If you have selected "Never", the text won't be updated.

Answer (score 0):

As per LiberOffice Writer [guide](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Documentation/Publications#LibreOffice_Writer_Guide), [Chapter 6 "Formatting sections, advanced"](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/images/e/e8/WG7206-FormattingPages_Advanced.pdf):

> Linking sections
>
> You can insert the contents of another document into the section and then have Writer update it
> whenever the other document is updated.

A bit further down it says:

> Updating links
>
> You can set Writer to update linked sections automatically, and you can also update links manually.
>
> Updating links automatically
>
> To set Writer to update links without prompting you, or to turn off automatic updating, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Choose Tools > Options > LibreOffice Writer > General. The dialog
>    displays general text document settings.
> 2. In the Update links when
>    loading section of the dialog, select one of the options:
>
>    – Always if you want Writer to update links automatically, without prompting you, whenever you open a document that contains links.
>
>    – On request if you want Writer to prompt you before updating links.
>
>    – Never if you do not want Writer to update links.
> 3. Click OK to save your settings.

I'd check the chapters concerning Images or Fields for information on linking and autoupdating external images.